# Minimum variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) of a parameter

Tags: statistics

can someone help me out with this question? I have also posted my approach for comments/review.

Question:

Let ${\hat{\theta}}$ be the MVUE for paremeter ${\theta}$, and let a and b be known constants with a $\neq$ 0. Show that ${\hat{\mu}} = a{\hat{\theta}} + b$ is the MVUE for parameter ${\hat{\mu}} = a{\theta} + b$.

My approach:

Since ${\hat{\theta}}$  is MVUE for ${\theta}$, ${\hat{\theta}}$  is an unbiased estimator for ${\theta}$, i.e. $E({\hat{\theta}} - {\theta}) = 0$  or alternately, $E({\hat{\theta}}) = E({\theta})$. Also because we can factorize the score as $s({\theta};y)$ into the form $b({\theta})(h(y) - g({\theta}))$ where  $b({\theta}) = 1$, $h(y) = {\theta}$ and $g({\theta})) = {\hat{\theta}}$

Now that we are given ${\hat{\mu}} = a{\hat{\theta}} + b$  and ${\hat{\mu}} = a{\theta} + b$. We know that ${\hat{\mu}}$ must be unbiased since $E({\hat{\mu}} - {\mu}) = E[(a{\hat{\theta}} + b) - (a{\hat{\theta}} + b)] = aE({\hat{\theta}}) - aE({\theta}) = 0$.

Furthermore, since the score can be factorized as $(1)[(a{\theta} + b) - (a{\hat{\theta}} + b)]$, ${\hat{\mu}}$ is MVUE.

Can someone look at this please and let me know your thoughts please?

Many thanks

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, the idea behind the proof is to note that if $\hat \theta$ is UMVUE for $\theta$, then $\hat \mu$ is also unbiased (as you observed), but also $\operatorname{Var}[\hat\mu] = a^2 \operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta]$; thus if $a \ne 0$, then the variance of $\hat \mu$ is minimized whenever the variance of $\hat \theta$ is also minimized.

Comment: Thanks heropup - just to check, why are we not able to use the part where we can factorize the score function as an indication that the parameter is MVUE?

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{var}(a\hat\theta+b) = a^2\operatorname{var}(\hat\theta)$, if there is some value of $a\theta+b$ for which the variance of some other estimator than $a\hat\theta+b$, say $T$, is smaller than the variance of $a\hat\theta+b$ then for the corresponding value of $\theta$, the estimator $(T-b)/a$ would be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ whose variance is smaller than the variance of $\hat\theta$ for that value of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I suppose I would use this part here as a "contradiction approach" together with heropup's framework